# SFML tutorial not even working

Tags: c++, codeblocks, libraries, sfml

I installed SFML on codeblocks with their tutorial, following it step by step. Everything has been checked and done correctly, yet their sample program is not even building correctly. It seems that codeblocks cannot even find the basic functions of SFML. 
What did I miss?

Error log :

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlNcL.jpg )

My code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post text as image, better include it in a code block.

Comment: The linker is complaining. Have you linked the SFML libraries (and not just included) them?

Comment: @Vasfed - not source, he links to a picture of the error messages

Comment: I linked them in the "Linker settings" on the build options. Like the tutorial said.

Comment: But If I don't give the path, how is codeblocks going to know where I put SFML libraries ?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I do not know if the log is copyable, but it's better to include error text as text, so that question can be searched by these error texts and be of some use to future readers

Comment: Log is not copyable. Edited my post to include my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very strange to give a library location `-L` and then explicitly link to the exact library. So, instead of giving the full path to the library, just give it's name. So, instead of `..\..\..\..\..\LOGICIELS\CodeBlocks\SFML\libs\libsfml-graphics-s-d.a` just say `sfml-graphics-s-d`. Do this for all libraries

When you see `-L..\..\..\..\..\..\LOGICIELS\CodeBlocks\SFML\lib` you are telling the compiler (linker) where to find the libraries. The convention with libraries is that they are prefaced with `lib` and followed by `.a`.  So, change you library linkage to just the name of your library, sans `lib` and `.a`

so, after `obj\Debug\main.o`, it should be `sfml-grphics-s-d sfml-window-a-d sfml-system-a-d sfml-main-d`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mLvPsGQ.jpg Not working. Same errors. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: `graphics, system, windows, main` libraries are all in your original link line but there is no `main` in the new one.  Also, you had `-s-d`, `-a-d` and `-d` as suffixes before but now they are all `-d`.   Additionally, the errors changed format from `sf::String::String` to `_imp___Zn@sf....` now, so you used to have c++ errors, you now have name mangled errors.

Comment: What was the end result?